# What is the meaning of the error ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 205 to array axis with dimension 26 and how to solve it

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

This is the code i wrote , i am trying to convert the non-numerical data to numeric. However it return an error **ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 205 to array axis with dimension 26**
The data is get from http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Automobile

```
automobile = pd.read_csv('imports-85.csv', names = ["symboling", 
"normalized-losses", "make", "fuel", "aspiration", "num-of-doors", "body-
style", "drive-wheels", "engine-location", "wheel-base", "length", "width", 
"height", " curb-weight", "engine-type", "num-of-cylinders","engine-
size","fuel-system","bore","stroke"," compression-ratio","horsepower","peak-
rpm","city-mpg","highway-mpg","price"])
X = automobile.drop('symboling',axis=1)
y = automobile['symboling']

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit([automobile])

print (le)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fit` method takes an array of `[n_samples]` see the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.fit). You're passing the entire data frame within a list. I'm pretty sure if you print the shape of your dataframe (`automobile.shape`) it will show a shape of `(205, 26)`

If you want to encode your data you need to do it one column at a time e.g.
`le.fit(automobile['make'])`.

Note, that this is not the correct way to encode categorical data, as the name suggests `LabelEncoder` is designed for labels and not input features. In scikit-learns current state you should use `OneHotEncoder`. There are plans in the next release for a [categorical encoder](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.CategoricalEncoder.html)